# Helm upgrade fails during updates in spec.resources.requests.storage as they are forbidden

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-statefulset

I am on `EKS 1.24` and using `ElasticSearch 6.5.4` helm chart.
I followed below steps to make updates to the disk size.

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: elasticsearch-data
    spec:
      {{ if and (.Values.enableEncryption) (eq .Values.enableEncryption true) }}
      storageClassName: gp2-encrypted
      {{ end }}
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: {{ .Values.volumeSize }}Gi
```

1. Updated `spec.resources.requests.storage` under `helm/templates` to the new desired value
2. Performed `helm upgrade`
3. I got below error

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: cannot patch "elasticsearch" with kind StatefulSet: StatefulSet.apps "elasticsearch" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', 'updateStrategy', 'persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy' and 'minReadySeconds' are forbidden
```

Possible solutions -

1. Delete the existing statefulset and apply new one with updated values - `kubectl delete statefulset elasticsearch && kubectl apply -f new-statefulset.yaml`
2. Deploy ES in multi-mode where Master, data and client will have a separate role

Now I am looking for a solution where I can handle it in existing helm chart configuration instead of converting my helm chart to [multi](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/main/elasticsearch/examples/multi/)

Comment: That error message says you can't change the `storage:` capacity after the StatefulSet has already been created.

Comment: I understand that this is Kubernetes limitations and there is open PR https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/3412. But since this is very common use case to bump up the size of disk and we dont want to do this manually every time by patching PVC `kubectl patch pvc {{ template "elasticsearch.fullname" . }}-data -p '{"spec":{"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"2Gi"}}}}' `

Answer (score 0):

I was able to follow below process to upgrade the disk size (manual) to avoid any downtime -

1. `kubectl delete sts <statefulset-name> --cascade=orphan`  (which will make sure the elasticsearch pods are in running state always)
2. `kubectl patch pvc {{ template "elasticsearch.fullname" . }}-data -p '{"spec":{"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"10Gi"}}}}'` [This will patch existing PVC to new disk size]
3. Then recreate sts with new updated disk size. [Either apply `helm upgrade` with new disk size OR apply `kubectl apply -f newsts.yaml`